# XCode 5 always behind other windows

Tags: macos, xcode5

Since upgrading to XCode 5 and Mountain Lion, Xcode is always behind all other windows.

For instance, I open up Safari or Finder to look at something and I have to close or minimize them in order to get back to XCode.  With XCode 4 I would leave several windows open and just click between them.

I know this is probably some stupid OSX setting that got changed in upgrading to Mountain Lion, but for the life of me I know not what!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure it's relevant here, maybe better suited to : http://apple.stackexchange.com/ . BTW, have you tried creating multiple desktops and putting Xcode there ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a localized, transient problem of unknown cause.

Comment: Same issue here - except with Xcode 4.x. In my case the problem disappeared after upgrading to Xcode 5 but your issue indicates that the root cause appears to be in there, still...

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working Friday, works fine today (Monday).

Go figure!